# Can't run javascript included in html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have code which is not displaying on my web pages. I put some html which is common to all pages into a separate html file (footer.html) and call it like this within each page of my site.

This is the head part.

```
<script src="w3.js"></script>
```

And here is the body part.

```
    <div w3-include-html="footer.html"></div>
    <script>
        w3.includeHTML();
    </script>
```

Here is the content of footer.html

```
<div id="footer";>
    <p>Copyright 2017<span style="float:right;">
    <script>
        var x = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        document.write(x);
        document.write(" last updated ");
        document.write(document.lastModified.substring(0,10));
    </script>
    </span></p>
</div>
```

The document.write's don't work.

Here is what I've tried already. moving the  and  out of the included html and putting into the main html.

I've tried substituting document.write with window.write (per sugestion of a previous post.

Neither solution works. But, when I copy the footer code right into my main html, then it works. That's the only way seems to, but doing that would defeat my purpose because I'd like to keep some common code like headers and footers in separate files.

(I took w3.js from www.w3schools.com)

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the **whole** html file with the css styling you used?

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors?

Comment: remove everything but the footer and see if it renders what you need. The error could have been above and it never got executed.

Comment: The supplied HTML is invalid. What's with the semicolon?

Answer (score 0):

The way that package works is by setting the innerHTML to your new HTML as a string. This does not cause the JS to fire. Unfortunately you will not be able to get this to work with that package. JQuery on the other hand will work to do what you are looking to do, just with a different architecture.

This is how includeHTML from https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js works

```
w3.includeHTML = function(cb) {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
    if (file) {
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;
          elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
          w3.includeHTML(cb);
        }
      }      
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      return;
    }
  }
  if (cb) cb();
};
```

Jquery (https://jquery.com/) is more complicated to track down exactly what it is doing, but you could do this:

Please let me know if this works. I did not really test it.

Head:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Body:

```
<div jq-include-html="footer.html"></div>
<script>
    (function () {
        var includes = $('[jq-include-html]');
        includes.each(function () {
            elem = $(this);
            url = elem.attr('jq-include-html');
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'text',
                url: url,
                success: function (res) {
                    elem.append(res);
                }
                error: function (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }
            });
        });
    }());
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the `jQuery` because what you have posted isn't using any `jQuery`... or non that I can see of....

Comment: Sorry jQuery is a common package. I was showing you the problem with the w3 school package, not the solution. I will update it.

Comment: @NewToJS you can give that a go. Let me know if it works. If not I can try and troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi Aduss, sorry didn't work. I did some reading, shouldn't the (function... be $(function...  ?